# How can I batch rename files by combining three variables and ignore file extensions?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, variable-substitution

I'm trying to create a script that renames a group of files. Normally they will be TIFs but sometimes an occasional oddball could be thrown in so I would like to rename the file and ignore the file extensions.

The file names will all be the same with the epoch time thrown in the middle as a differentiator. The end result will be similar to this:

```
Name1=CLMSFILE

Name2=Epoch

Name3=_A BUNCH OF OTHERTEXT_WITH_A_MIXTURE OF UNDERSCORES AND_SPACES

CLMSFILE53253_A BUNCH OF OTHERTEXT_WITH_A_MIXTURE OF UNDERSCORES AND_SPACES.TIF (or other extension)
```

This is what I currently have

```
#Rename files and insert epoch time
name1=$CLMSFILE
name2=$(date  +%s%3N)
name3=$_A\ BUNCH\ OF\ OTHERTEXT_WITH_A_MIXTURE\ OF\ UNDERSCORES\ AND_SPACES

for f in *; do
  newname=$name1$name2$name3
  mv -n "$f" "${newname}"
done
```

After running this I only get the first file renamed except it ignores the first variable and there is no extension.

```
1653049404956 _A BUNCH OF OTHERTEXT_WITH_A_MIXTURE OF UNDERSCORES AND_SPACES
220220217SOMEORG20003_01.TIF
220220217SOMEORG30004_01.TIF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your shell script that lead to the errors you observe:

1. You say that the first name part is to be `CLSMFILE`. However, in the variable assignment you state `name1=$CLMSFILE`, so you assign to the first part the content of *a shell variable named `CLSMFILE`*, which likely doesn't exist and therefore is empty. The same is actually also true for the `name3` part, but you happen to start the string with an `_`, and `$_` has a special meaning in the shell so interpretation stops immediately after the `_` and the remaining part of the string is imported unchanged to your variable.
2. Your script would try to rename all files to the same name. Luckily, you used the `-n` option, or you would have lost all but the last of the files in your directory.

   The reason is that the `date` command in `name2=$(date ...)` is only evaluated *at the moment the assignment is made, not every time the `$name2` variable is used*. So it is constant for all iterations of the loop.
3. You state that you want to have a filename extension, but you forgot to add an extension to the file. `mv` renames *the entire filename*, not only the part before the `.`, simply because more than one `.` is allowed in filenames.

I would recommend that you use [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone tool, to catch errors in shell scripts.

The following modification should work:

```
name1="CLMSFILE"
name3="_A BUNCH OF OTHERTEXT_WITH_A_MIXTURE OF UNDERSCORES AND_SPACES"

for f in *; do
  basename=${f%.*}
  newbasename="$name1$(date  +%s%3N)$name3"
  newname=${f/$basename/$newbasename}
  mv -n "$f" "${newname}"
done
```

This uses shell string manipulation to

- store the "basename" part of `$f`, i.e. everything up to the last `.`-separated part, in a variable `$basename`
- generate the new basename according to your rule, but run the `date` command for every loop iteration
- replace the `$basename` sub-string of `$f` with `$newbasename`
- rename the file accordingly

Ideally, you would replace the `mv -n ...` part with something like

```
echo "Renaming '$f' to '$newname'"
```

until you are sure that the name-generating logic works correctly.